# angularjs infinite scroll in a POP up window?

Tags: angularjs, lazy-loading, infinite-scroll

Actually i have Pop Up window, which has to be list some object by angular ajax call.And i need to load object in the manner of Lazy loading,while my popup window's scroll reaches the bottom of the same.But lazy loading occurs while the browser's scroll reaches the bottom.

my Question is how to implement inifinte-scroll in Div on pop up window.???

Note :I am using ng-infinite-scroll.min.js - v1.0.0 - 2013-02-23 version .

```
<div id="fo" ng-show="searchParameters.showOrganization">
    <div id="containerInfiniteScroll" class="container">

        <div ng-show="nonFeaturedOrganizationList.length==0" class="nores">No Results Found (Organization)</div>
        <div infinite-scroll='loadPaginationOrgs(true)' nfinite-scroll-disabled="disabled" infinite-scroll-distance="1"
            infinite-scroll-container='"#containerInfiniteScroll"'>
            <div class="ende-widget1 grant-mar1 featuredPeeopleAndOrg-w" ng-repeat="orgId in nonFeaturedOrganizationList">

                <div ng-click="showBrowseFeatureDialog(false);selectFeature(orgId,6,organizationFeatures)">
                    <div my-organization org-id="orgId" style-index="$index" />
                </div>
                <div class="featuredPeeopleAndOrg-this">
                    <a ng-click="showBrowseFeatureDialog(false);selectFeature(orgId,6,organizationFeatures)">Feature this</a>
                </div>

                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: "Please give the solution for it."  The solution for *what*? you never asked a question, you merely listed some code and some requirement.  It's not clear at all what is actually wrong here.

Comment: I think he as the same problem as me, loadPaginationOrgs is not triggered in popup window